# robotframework : failed to locate keywords outside the folder

Tags: python, robotframework

```
folder structure

Project
  |
  |_ _folder1  (abc.robot)
  |
  |_ _folder2  (def.robot)
  |      |_ _ folder3 (ghi.robot)
  |
  |
  |
  setup.robot
```

inside folder1 abc.robot

```
#abc.robot 
#create session api call

*** Settings ***
Library     RequestsLibrary
Resource    /setup.robot

Post_new_user
    create session    newsession        ${url}
    ${body}=    create dictionary      mobile_prefix=${mobile_prefix}   mobile_number=${mobile_number}
    ${headers}=  create dictionary     Content-Type=application/json
    ${response}=    post request    newsession      newuser/register      data=${body}     headers=${headers}

    #validations
    ${status_code}=     convert to string    ${response.status_code}
    should be equal    ${status_code}       200
```

inside folder2 def.robot

```
#def.robot
#test data driven with robot

*** Settings ***
Resource    ../../ghi.robot
Test Template  Registration Test

*** Test Cases ***
test1       +12     9999999991
test2       +12     9999999992
test3       +12     9999999993


*** Keywords ***
Registration Test
    [Arguments]    ${mobile_prefix}     ${mobile_number}
    a mobile prefix ${mobile_prefix}
    a mobile number ${mobile_number}
    Post_new_user
```

inside folder3

```
#ghi.robot
#set of keywords / steps to call

*** Keywords ***
a mobile prefix ${mobile_prefix}
    set test variable  ${mobile_prefix}  ${mobile_prefix}

a mobile number ${mobile_number}
    set test variable  ${mobile_number}  ${mobile_number}
```

step.robot

```
*** Variable ***
${url}=     https://example/com
```

using test data driver for robot framework
but when def.robot run
there is always a problem with location of the file

1. Resource file '\setup.robot' does not exist.
2. Resource file 'ghi.robot' does not exist.
3. No keyword with name 'a mobile prefix ${mobile_prefix}' found.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try below:
Resource file `Resource      ../setup.robot` 

Resource file `Resource      ../../folder2/folder3/ghi.robot`

Comment: already tried it , but still got the same error :(

Comment: Always use project path. We have 2 builtin variables ${EXECDIR}, ${CURDIR}. Refer to user guide.  Your path will look like ${EXECDIR}${/}setup.robot

Comment: Link - http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#toc-entry-285

Answer (score 0):

```
#abc.robot 
...
Resource    ../setup.robot


#def.robot
...
Resource    ./folder3/ghi.robot
```

Comment: is there a difference between single "." and double ".." ?

Comment: .. is parent folder but . is current folder

Comment: @ningpra Have you tried my solution?